# Prevent SQL Server concurrency insert locking

Tags: sql-server, locking, buffer, transactionscope

I have 45 `active` concurrent insert transaction that each transaction try to insert (only insert without any select or update) about 250 rows to some tables.

The problem is when a transaction wants to insert the data into the tables, there are about 1000 X and IX locks (`sys.dm_tran_locks`) on multi index rows and index pages.

I have moved index files to an SSD but it didn't help and I still have a lot of pending transactions which each transaction takes about 200ms to 4000ms to be completed according to `Adult logout` on SQL profiler.

The Buffer I/O, Buffer latch, Lock, Latch, Logging Wait times are 0 or very low in activity monitor.

I have tried to increase number of transactions, but it also didn't help and number of execution in `Activity monitor` is still same.

My system info:

- 2x E5,
- SSD Raid 0 for log files,
- HDD Raid 10 for data,
- SSD Raid 0 for indexes,
- +64GB DDR3,
- SQL Server 2014 SP2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiply suggestions depending on what exactly causes the problem:

1. Your indexes. Every time you do an insert SQL Server updates all indexes on a table. So, solution would be to decrease number of indexes on your tables.
2. IDENTITY column contention. Try to replace your `IDENTITY` columns by `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.
3. Extra I/O associated with page splits. Regularly rebuild clustered index with lower FILLFACTOR (Extreme scenario: <50%).
4. PFS contention. Create multiple files in your DB, and split indexes/tables to them.
5. You are on SQL2014. Try to use In-Memory features.

Comment: 1. I have already disabled/removed lots of indexes. 2. I have changed all of the Primaries as non-identity, bigint and initialize it on business level. 3. fill factors are more than 90. 4. I'll do it and, but it make any change if I use separate partition for each table? because the I/O will be the same. 5. In-memory is impossible I think, according to limits on 2014 and size of db (4TB)

Comment: For #3 you have to look at fragmentation and number of page splits during the insert. If it is the case you can lower Fillfactor down to 50% and even lower. Data should not be sequential by clustered index, then you can insert to multiple pages at once. For #4 you can split one table to more than one file.

Comment: Many thanks for your tips, I have reduced fill-factor for some Indexes to 20%, and the pages filled to 70% with minimum fragmentation. Also I have added two file for big tables (one file group) and moved them to another HDD. In this case inserts and selects will have better performance because in two HDD perform the operations ( one for small tables and the other for large that use RAID10). Also I have created sequential range-id rather than sequential that let create multi index page with minimum locking. Finally I do bulk inserts with "Insert bulk" that increased performance up to 400%.

Comment: Impressive result. Just do not forget to do `INDEX REBUILD` before the loading to get back to 20% fillfactor. You might try higher value such as 35%-40% to get 95%-100% pages filled by the end of the operation.